# Storybook + Vue.js + Sass + npm7 workspaces won't compile

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2, storybook

I have a project which I am breaking into multiple workspaces using npm7.

I am using sass in vue components in a package (another workspace), and importing that package into my current workspace.

When I use sass in the workspace in which storybook is running, it compiles fine.
When I use css in the other workspace it compiles fine.

When I use sass in another workspace, it doesn't find the loaders.

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (39:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../node_modules/vue-docgen-loader/lib/index.js
 * ../node_modules/vue-docgen-loader/lib/index.js
 * ../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| 
> @import '../../../bootstrap4/scss/functions';
| @import '../../../bootstrap4/scss/variables';
| 
    at handleParseError (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:469:19)
    at /srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at context.callback (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.module.exports (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/vue-docgen-loader/lib/index.js:28:5)
    at LOADER_EXECUTION (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:119:14)
    at runSyncOrAsync (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:120:4)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at context.callback (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.module.exports (/srv/insight_lerna/submodules/insight_core/insight-javascript/node_modules/vue-docgen-loader/lib/index.js:28:5)
```

My main.js works for local sass. It is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ],
  "webpackFinal": async (config, { configType }) => {

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
}
```

Is it possible to use storybook with npm workspaces?

I am using storybook 6.2.8.

I am using vue.js 2.6.12

Comment: did you install node-sass??

Comment: node-sass 4.13.0 is installed. Saas compilation works find in storybook workspaces. Problem is in other workspaces brought in via npm7. I believe therefore that I am seeing a webpack config type problem not a vue/sass type problem.

Comment: I created a pastebin with the output of  "start-storybook --debug-webpack" : https://pastebin.com/QbGgDgm7

Comment: I created a repository demo'ing the issue here: https://github.com/kevingill1966/storybook-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further investigation, I found the error is in the line:

```
include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
```

I removed this line and it worked fine. Clearly it is limiting the rule to the current workspace instead of all workspaces.